Combine i18next and authjs v5 middleware
I just try to figure out how to combine 2 middlewares
And both of them has config, my config is pretty good for use, and if it's possible I want to keep it, how to combain it ?
Stack:

next 14,
next-auth 5.0.0-beta.15,
i18next 23.10.1,
next-i18n-router 5.4.0

current middleware:
import authConfig from '@/auth.config';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import {
    API_ROUTES,
    authRoutes,
    DEFAULT_REDIRECT,
    publicRoutes,
} from '@/routes';
export const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-expect-error
export default auth((req) => {
    const { nextUrl } = req;
    const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

    const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(API_ROUTES.AUTH);
    const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
    const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

    if (isApiAuthRoute) {
        return null;
    }

    if (isAuthRoute) {
        // The way to create an absolute url
        if (isLoggedIn)
            return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_REDIRECT, nextUrl));

        return null;
    }

    if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
        // Redirect to previous page after login
        let callbackUrl = nextUrl.pathname;

        if (nextUrl.search) {
            callbackUrl += nextUrl.search;
        }

        const encodedCallbackUrl = encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl);

        return Response.redirect(
            new URL(`/auth/login?callbackUrl=${encodedCallbackUrl}`, nextUrl),
        );
    }

    return null;
});

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
    matcher: [
        // Exclude files with a "." followed by an extension, which are typically static files.
        // Exclude files in the _next directory, which are Next.js internals.

        '/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)',
        // Re-include any files in the api or trpc folders that might have an extension
        '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
    ],
};

required next-i18n-router middleware:
import {i18nRouter} from "next-i18n-router";
import i18nConfig from "@/i18nConfig";
import {NextRequest} from "next/server";


export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    return i18nRouter(req, i18nConfig);
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/((?!api|static|.*\\\\..*|_next).*)'
}

